# free XML designer and virtualizer

Tags: xml, eclipse, workflow

I have an xml code that looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata><fields><field-order/></fields><roles><role name="DEFAULT3_MOD"><state status="0"/><state 

status="1"/><state status="99"><transition status="99"/></state></role><role name="DEFAULT2"><state 

status="0"/><state status="1"><transition status="1"/></state><state status="99"/></role><role 

name="DEFAULT"><state status="0"><transition status="1"/></state><state status="1"/><state 

status="99"/></role></roles><states><state status="0" label="New"/><state status="1" label="Open"/><state 

status="99" label="Closed"/></states></metadata>
```

Can anyone recommend any xml designer, so that, I can virtualized the xml easily?  I tried eclipse,  but, not so friendly enough. Any other free tool?

Comment: what do you mean by virtualize?  Do you mean clean it up and indent it to make it easier to read?

Comment: show the xml in graphical format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by virtualize, but if you want to tidy your XML, you can use an html tidying utility such as http://infohound.net/tidy/

Just paste your XML in there, choose the options you need, and it will spit out cleaned source.

Answer (score 1):

The asker doesn't mean graphical format.

What the asker wants is something that will display his XML as it would on a website, stylised by either CSS or XSLT, though as they have not provided CSS or XSLT, I'm sure what they really are asking for is a website or software to help them create the XSLT/CSS by means of how they want the final outcome to be (for example WYSIWYG editing).

- [Microsoft XML Notepad 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=72d6aa49-787d-4118-ba5f-4f30fe913628&displaylang=en&displaylang=en#Requirements)
- [Syntext Serna](http://webdesign.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=webdesign&cdn=compute&tm=405&f=20&su=p284.13.342.ip_p504.6.342.ip_&tt=3&bt=0&bts=1&st=9&zu=http://www.syntext.com/products/serna-free/)